# Redirecting the outbound connection of an ip to an ip

Tags: iptables, android

Im using an app. Now, i want the outbound connection of that app will redirect to to another ip so that it doesn't go back to that app. How will i do it using iptables? How will i know the ip of that app? 
P.s I just started using android few months ago and my phone is rooted and im new to iptables and other root required apps. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks! Sorry for my bad English.